# C++ Variable Assignment with If statement

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to program a system where the user gets to choose if they were to enter a date in Day, Month, or Year with a combo box. Here's my code:

```cpp
    double Years;
    
    if (FinancialTermType->SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        String ^ TermTextbox = Term->Text;
        std::wstring TermString(TermTextbox->Data());
        Years = std::stod(TermString);
    }
    else if (FinancialTermType->SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        String ^ TermTextbox = Term->Text;
        std::wstring TermString(TermTextbox->Data());
        double month = std::stod(TermString);
        Years = (month / 12);
    }
    else if (FinancialTermType->SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        String ^ TermTextbox = Term->Text;
        std::wstring TermString(TermTextbox->Data());
        double day = std::stod(TermString);
        Years = (day / 365);
    }
```

but it warns that `warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'Years' used`. Thanks

Comment: If `FinancialTermType->SelectedIndex` is some value other than 0, 1, or 2, then none of your if-tests will pass, and `Years` will never be initialized.

Comment: You either need to assign an initial value to `Years` or add an `else` statement

Comment: @JeremyFriesner There are 2 items (0-2).

Comment: @AirbusFan4444 if there are only 3 possible values for `SelectedIndex`, consider using an enum class with descriptive names instead. For example, `enum class InputKind { years, months, days };` Then `SelectedIndex` would be of type `InputKind`

Comment: Also, you can factor out common code (that reads the double value) and place it outside the `if`s

Comment: Sometimes it helps to [play devil's advocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). That is, as you write out a request for help, include an argument as to why the compiler is wrong, why your code is undeniably correct. If you pay attention to the details, you might find the answer before you post.

Comment: @AirbusFan4444 you may know that the combo box has only three items (0, 1, and 2), but your compiler doesn't know that; hence the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a initial value for Years, for example `Double Years = 0` when defining the variable.